# aws api gateway and lamda - how to get event.body

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm new to aws and I have a strange problem of getting the body of event inside my lamda handler function.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: event.body
    };
    return response;
};
```

[image]

When I run test I get

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200
}
```

However when I only return event

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: event <=====
    };
    return response;
};
```

I get

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
  }
}
```

I'm using node 8.10. Does anybody knows what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks like event *is* the body, considering when you assign event to body you just get an object with key123, val123 rather than a body key

Answer (score 2):

The test event in to Lambda console is exactly what you get as the `event` parameter in your Lambda handler. When you put `{"a":1}`, you get `{"a":1}`.

You can simulate a different event types of AWS service (SNS, S3, API Gateway) selecting a template from the combobox.

As you are returning a HTTP response, you want probably to simulate an API Gateway event, it could look like this:

```
{
  "body": "{\"a\":1}",
  "pathParameters": {
    "id": "XXX"
  },
  "resource": "/myres",
  "path": "/myres",
  "httpMethod": "GET",
  "isBase64Encoded": true,
  "requestContext": {
    "authorizer": {
      "tenantId": "TEST"
    },
    "accountId": "123456789012",
    "resourceId": "123456",
    "stage": "test",
    "requestId": "test-request-id",
    "requestTime": "09/Apr/2015:12:34:56 +0000",
    "requestTimeEpoch": 1428582896000,
    "path": "/myres",
    "resourcePath": "/myres,
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "apiId": "1234567890",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1"
  }
}
```

Then you will get the body in `event.body` as JSON string - you can convert it into an object by `JSON.parse(event.body)`.

When returning, you have to serialize the response body with `JSON.stringify`:

```
return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stingify({your:'object'})
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: event.body
    };
    return response;
};
```

to

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(event.body)
    };
    return response;
};
```

The body you return in API Gateway must be stringified, otherwise it doesn't know how to deal with the response.

Comment: When the event comes from API Gateway it's already serialized, so `body: JSON.stringify(event.body)` makes not much sense. The point is to understand the difference between types of events.

Comment: I meant "event" rather than "event.body". Thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: That's better! :-)

Comment: Well, not really. The OP said when returning `event.body` he gets nothing but a 200. When returning the `event`, however, he gets the full body. So I'll edit it back to JSON.stringify(event.body) (which is what he wanted to achieve at the beginning). This will force API Gateway to return the values the OP expects.

Comment: (I do agree that events send stringified JSONs, but since he's doing it manually from the console, then JSON.stringify(event.body) will do what he wants)

Comment: Yes, but he is doing it wrong. When one simulate an API Gateway event with a wrong request, he gets a wrong response. Your answer will work in this particular situation, but not later productive... That's why I tried to explain it in my answer.

Comment: I understand. My idea was really to cover his scenario as there are many other questions on how to access the body for a given event, but thanks for explaining your point